# How do I get page content of redirect page?

Tags: php, curl

After I execute the curl I have a header which takes me to a new website, but I lose control not allowing me to capture the page contents of the redirect page. How would I do this? I'm very new to php, so any help is appreciated.

Comment: Where's your code ? Please clarify: ***"allowing me to capture the page contents of the redirect page"***

Comment: Parse the html and look for a redirect. If a redirect is in the code make a curl to the new url

Answer (score 2):

If the page is redirecting you can use CURL option to follow the location:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
```

> CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION:   TRUE to follow any "Location: " header that the
>   server sends as part of the HTTP header (note this is recursive, PHP
>   will follow as many "Location: " headers that it is sent, unless
>   CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS is set).
>   [Source](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php)

Comment: Would it change anything if the redirect is the page after a login which has a specific session?

Comment: It will follow the header redirects, regardless of session. So if you manage curl to use session, login to website and if that website sends header redirect then curl will follow it.